# How can I center the heading?

Tags: html, css

The menu button is pushing the heading aside. How can I fix that the heading ignores the pushing? The Code is below. I heard of clear but it is not working. Is ist a padding or margin of the element?

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0e4675 25%,#00215a 75%); 
}

#in {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

#heading {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 5px solid #ffffff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-left: 6px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
 padding-right: 6px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 transition: all 1.5s;
 display: inline-block;
 clear: both;
}

#navigationbutton {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 38px;
 height: 38
}

.text {
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
   <div id="in">
    <header id="header">
                    <h1 id="heading">App-Title</h1>
                    <img id="navigationbutton" src="media/image/navigation.svg">
                </header>
    <main id="main">
     <div id="textarea">
     <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
     </div>
    </main>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, add your code to the answer so we can help you.

Comment: You should add a code example, ideally including with CSS. Otherwise there won't be any chance to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to make "header" a block with a relative position and the navigation to a block with absolute position:

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0e4675 25%,#00215a 75%); 
}

#in {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
  display:block;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
  position:relative;top:0;left:0;
}

#heading {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 5px solid #ffffff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-left: 6px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
 padding-right: 6px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 transition: all 1.5s;
 display: inline-block;
 clear: both;
}

#navigationbutton {

 width: 38px;
 height: 38px;
    position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;
}

.text {
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
   <div id="in">
    <header id="header">
                    <h1 id="heading">App-Title</h1>
                    <img id="navigationbutton" src="media/image/navigation.svg">
                </header>
    <main id="main">
     <div id="textarea">
     <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
     </div>
    </main>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not quite sure if I get you right. But if, you just want to move the `h1` element back to the left side, you can simply add a negative margin to it.

I've added a negative left margin to the `#heading` id.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0e4675 25%,#00215a 75%); 
}

#in {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

#heading {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 5px solid #ffffff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-left: 6px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
 padding-right: 6px;
 margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left:-38px;
 transition: all 1.5s;
 display: inline-block;
 clear: both;
}

#navigationbutton {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 38px;
 height: 38
}

.text {
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
   <div id="in">
    <header id="header">
                    <h1 id="heading">App-Title</h1>
                    <img id="navigationbutton" src="media/image/navigation.svg">
                </header>
    <main id="main">
     <div id="textarea">
     <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
     </div>
    </main>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things, use max width because if you shrink it on my screen the body is bigger than the window. Also, just use absolute positioning.

```
        html {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0e4675 25%,#00215a 75%);    
        }

        #in {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        main {
            width: 80%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #header {
            border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
            position:relative;
        }

        #heading {
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            color: #ffffff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            border: 5px solid #ffffff;
            display: inline-block;
            padding-bottom: 4px;
            padding-left: 6px;
            letter-spacing: 0.01em;
            padding-right: 6px;
            margin-top: 16px;
            transition: all 1.5s;
            display: inline-block;
            clear: both;
        }

        #navigationbutton {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 38px;
            height: 38
        }

        .text {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
```